# Python delete file in multiple folders

Tags: python, file, operating-system

In multiple folders I have a file called `_status.json`
e.g.:

```
C:\Users\Me\.fscrawler\Folder1\_status.json
C:\Users\Me\.fscrawler\Folder2\_status.json
....
C:\Users\Me\.fscrawler\*\_status.json
```

I want to write a short python code, to delete all those files.

I already tried the following code, but it does not work. I dont know why, but I think the solution is pretty easy

```
import os
os.remove(C:\Users\Me\.fscrawler\*\_status.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module, and use it to find the files:

example:

```py
import glob
relative_path_to_files = glob.glob('**/_status.json', recursive=True)
```

then you can operate on the list as you wish :)

**Edit:**

`relative_path_to_files` is a *list*, so you have to iterate over its elements and operate on them:

here is a complete example to find all `_status.json` in the current directory and its sub-tree recursively:

```py
import glob
import os

for f in glob.glob('**/_status.json', recursive=True):
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: please see my problem below :)

Comment: can you print `relative_path_to_files`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to walk through all the subfolders to find and delete the file.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for name in files:
        if name == '_status.json':
            #delete the file
```

Comment: please see my problem below!

Comment: Just use the code above and pass "C:\Users\Me\.fscrawler" as the value for folder_path variable. Let me know if it works

Comment: Error: cannot find file "_status.json", for the "#"-part in your code I worte `os.remove(name)`. Maybe this is my mistake?